# How to access Pylons config from a repoze.who authenticator

Tags: pylons, repoze.who

I'm trying to access the Pylons configuration from inside a repoze.who "authenticator".. I'm using `from pylons import config`, but it looks like it returns a configuration with default values, not the ones from production.ini.. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/browse_thread/thread/4462c515178c742a) that suggests two options:

1. Passing the config directly to the authenticator instance during middleware setup
2. Adding a `pylons.config.update(config)` at the bottom of `load_environment`

Answer (score 0):

You must using `pylons.config` after calling `load_environment(global_conf, app_conf)` in `config/middleware.py` or use direct `app_conf`

Comment: Well the authenticator gets called by the login process, so AFAIK I *am* after the `load_environment` call